# Travis-Ci not importing utilities

Tags: travis-ci

I have a script of the following shape:

```
main.py
utilities/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
```

In main.py I import the function bar from foo.py:

```
from utilities.foo import bar
```

However, Travis cannot import this, returning:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities.foo'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how or why, but changing the name of the `utilities` folder to `utils` solves the issue.